# Safe to remove unused, default nginx files (fastcgi, uwsgi, scgi)?

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx purely as a reverse proxy. My `/etc/nginx/` looks like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    6 Jul  3 14:44 conf.d
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    6 Jul  3 14:44 default.d
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1.1K Jul  3 14:44 fastcgi.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1.1K Jul  3 14:44 fastcgi.conf.default
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  964 Jul  3 14:44 fastcgi_params
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  964 Jul  3 14:44 fastcgi_params.default
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2.8K Jul  3 14:44 koi-utf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2.2K Jul  3 14:44 koi-win
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3.9K Jul  3 14:44 mime.types
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3.9K Jul  3 14:44 mime.types.default
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1.2K Oct 11 15:41 nginx.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2.6K Jul  3 14:44 nginx.conf.default
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  596 Jul  3 14:44 scgi_params
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  596 Jul  3 14:44 scgi_params.default
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4.0K Oct  2 20:54 sites-available
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   96 Oct  5 09:38 sites-enabled
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  623 Jul  3 14:44 uwsgi_params
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  623 Jul  3 14:44 uwsgi_params.default
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3.6K Jul  3 14:44 win-utf
```

My `nginx.conf` includes only the contents of `sites-enabled` as well as `mime.types`. Can I delete files like `scgi_params` without affecting my setup?

What about files like `koi-utf` and `win-utf`, do I need them? They don't seem to be referenced by `nginx.conf`.

Comment: Nginx won't start if there's a config problem. Why not move/delete them and find out?

Comment: I'm more worried about "implicitly" dropping to some sketchy defaults.

Comment: Deleting files you aren't using isn't going to do anything. Nginx doesn't have any inbuilt defaults of any relevance, perse, and isn't going to load files unless you tell it to. Alternatively just google the name of each file to determine their purpose.